# custom function in FlutterFlow: cant return int value of firestore document

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

Im trying to sum an integer field in my firestore document collection, although I keep gettings errors. It looks like because firestore store integers as "num".

> A value of type 'Future' can't be returned from the function 'calculateTotalItemQty' because it has a return type of 'int'.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
import '/flutter_flow/lat_lng.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/place.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/uploaded_file.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart';
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/auth/firebase_auth/auth_util.dart';

int calculateTotalItemQty(
  String? itemId,
  String? businessId,
) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  // sum value of all itemQty in purchaseLine where itemId is itemId and businessId is businessId
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('purchases')
      .where('itemId', isEqualTo: itemId)
      .where('businessId', isEqualTo: businessId)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
    int totalQty = 0;
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      int value = doc['itemQty'];
      totalQty += value.toInt();
    });
    return totalQty;
  }).catchError((error) {
    print('Error getting total item qty: $error');
    return null;
  });

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

Tried to use .toInt() but still not working

Comment: As error suggests you, your method `calculateTotalItemQty` returns int instead of Future. Getting data from firestore is asynchronous, you need to await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you can make your function `async` and return a Future.

However, in FlutterFlow's custom code section, "Custom Actions" can return a Future and not "Custom Function". So you can move the code under a Custom Action snippet and it should work.

You can call that custom action in your Action Flow Editor where you can get that return `int` value and then do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `await` keyword in front of Firebase method. Like below code

```
Future<int?> calculateTotalItemQty(
  String? itemId,
  String? businessId,
) async {   
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('purchases')
      .where('itemId', isEqualTo: itemId)
      .where('businessId', isEqualTo: businessId)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
    int totalQty = 0;
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      int value = doc['itemQty'];
      totalQty += value.toInt();
    });
    return totalQty;
  }).catchError((error) {
    print('Error getting total item qty: $error');
    return null;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function is attempting to return a `Future<int>` instead of just an `int`. To resolve this, make your function `async` and utilize the `await` keyword for the Firestore query.

```
Future<int> calculateTotalItemQty(
  String? itemId,
  String? businessId,
) async {
  try {
   /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  // sum value of all itemQty in purchaseLine where itemId is itemId and businessId is businessId
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('purchases')
        .where('itemId', isEqualTo: itemId)
        .where('businessId', isEqualTo: businessId)
        .get();

    int totalQty = 0;
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      int value = doc['itemQty'] as int;
      totalQty += value;
    });

    return totalQty;
  } catch (error) {
    print('Error getting total item qty: $error');
    return 0;
  }
  
  
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It seems logical to me but im still getting same error.

"A value of type 'Future<int>' can't be returned from the function 'calculateTotalItemQty' because it has a return type of 'int?'."

Comment: Please try returning Future<int?>. This must match the expected return type in the calling function. If you're still having trouble, could you give me more information or pinpoint where the problem is happening? I'm here to help and will do my best to provide further assistance.

Comment: Important to note that when you return a Future in FlutterFlow, it should be under "Custom Actions" in FlutterFlow and NOT a "Custom Function" (which is supposed to be simple input output functions).

So you can move the entire code under a Custom Function and it should work!

Comment: @pblead26 Yes this was it! my mistake, I did look up as well. Thank you for the answer.